# Where is the Windows Security Button or what does it look like?

Tags: security

Log in says Press CTRL + Alt + Delete or use the Windows Security button to unlock this computer. Nothing happens when I press CTRL Alt Delete.  So, where is the Windows Security Button?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows Security button is an extra button on most Tablet PCs.

Here is a picture showing its location for a Compaq Tablet PC tc1100:

[image]

Reference [Compaq Tablet PC tc1100, tc1000 - Identifying the Buttons](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c00231302-2%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=376810&ac.admitted=1414345616057.876444892.199480143#N10156)

> **Windows Security Button**
>
> **Security Button**: Press the Windows Security Button with the pen tip or a small object like the end of a paper clip to enter the Ctrl
>   +Alt +Delete command while you are in Windows or the reset command while you are in Setup utility. Ctrl +Alt +Delete command cannot be
>   entered using the Ctrl , Alt , and Delete keys on the on-screen
>   keyboard.
>
> **Ctrl +Alt +Delete Function**: When the tablet PC is in
>   Windows, the Windows Security button clears your work from the screen
>   and displays the Windows Security window in which you can lock, log
>   off, or shut down the tablet PC, initiate Standby or Hibernation, or
>   open Task Manager.
>
> - The Shut Down option in the 
>     Ctrl +Alt +Delete
>     window enables you to safely shut down the tablet PC if the system has become unresponsive.
> - Task Manager displays the status of all open applications and enables you to close an application that has become unresponsive. If
>     the system remains unresponsive after selecting Shut Down in the
>     Windows Security window, slide and hold the power switch for 4
>     seconds. For information about using the Ctrl +Alt +Delete
>     command in non-Windows applications, refer to the application documentation.
>
> **Reset Function**: When the Setup utility is open, the Windows Security button simulates the reset button found on some computers.
>   When the tablet PC is reset, the tablet PC restarts and all unsaved
>   information is lost. The reset function can be used to restore
>   functionality when the system has become unresponsive. For information
>   about Setup utility, refer to the Managing System BIOS module.